# How can I restore my display settings in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, display-settings

A kid pressed some keys (possibly some hot-keys) while I was away. It caused the display to turn to a reddish tint.

I want to change it back to default. I don't seem to find any simple way to do that.

Most of the forums I read discuss using some tools like colour management. But I don't want to customize my display. I just want the default look back.

I have already spent more than an hour searching for a solution without any luck.

Please provide a simple solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a basic setting on the windows Action Center. All you have to do is press the notification button, and press night light to turn it off.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was not aware of the night light setting.

Answer (score 5):

Since my Creators Update does not have a "notification" button on the Action Center (which is actually "Security and Maintenance"), here is the canonical way to access the Night Light Setting:

> Settings (on the start menu) -- System -- Display

Or,

> Right-click on the desktop, and choose Display Settings.